# Chinese font cut off in iOS app with custom font

Tags: ios, fonts, uifont

We're currently localizing our iPhone app to various languages, one of them being Chinese. Throughout the app we use Menlo as font, but now when iOS has to display Chinese characters those are cut off at the top. I guess this is because Menlo does not feature these characters and thus iOS has to fall back to the system font for Chinese which has a different line height?

What is the recommended approach here?

[image: Settings screen]

Comment: Mark Gaensicke any solution find about your issue. i got same problem in my app

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom table cell try to increase the height of the textView.

If you are using default tableview cell you can try setting the font size to 0, the text should be auto-sized as appropriate.

Hope this helps.. :)